# In dimensional consistency checks is $\mathrm{M}=\sqrt{3}\mathrm{M}$ true?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

When checking an equation with dimensional consistency, if I get
$\mathrm{M}=\sqrt{3}\mathrm{M}$

should I be worried? or the coefficients don't matter because we are concerned about dimensions?

Comment: I think adding together mass(?) and length(?) is not so good, at least in physics.

Comment: @Botond  Yes, that was a typo, I have corrected it!

Comment: Addition and multiplication by dimension-less constants does not change units.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Adding?  So we can have $\mathrm{M}+2=2+3\mathrm{ M}$?  I don't understand what it means to add a dimensionless constant to something with dimensions.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Is the addition really 'works'?

Comment: I meant "addition of variables with the same unit" and "multiplication by dimension-less constants" does not change units, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: okay thank you. this has answered my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the $\sqrt{3}$ is simply a non-dimensional constant, there is no problem

As a similar example the period of a basic pendulum is measured with the dimension of time.  The obvious factors potentially affecting the period are mass, length (distance) and gravitational acceleration (distance divided by the square of time). Dimensional analysis of these would suggest the period could be proportional to $\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$, while physical analysis would suggest something close to simple harmonic motion with $$T \approx 2\pi \sqrt\frac{L}{g}$$ The $2\pi$ is a non-dimensional constant and neither affects the correctness of the dimensional analysis nor can be found by it